# Will ubuntu work well on Asus K501U?

Tags: drivers, asus

I've been trying to find an answer to this question but it doesn't seem to be answered.  I've also tried looking up specific drivers for the hardware and stuff but seem to be too new at this to really know what to look for.

I did find one post where they said ubuntu had a bunch of problem on this model of laptop so I'm trying to see if anyone else had any success with this Asus model.  Has anyone had any success with installing ubuntu on an Asus K501U?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's only one way of knowing: **Testing**.

Ubuntu uses the Linux kernel. Unlike Windows' NT kernel, Linux comes with most drivers built-in, so in 99% of the cases every piece of hardware will be "plug-and-play": you insert it, it works. No need to install anything.

But sometimes you may have some trouble, specially with extremely new hardware, since Linux may not have its drivers yet. But, again, in 99% of the cases you can solve the problems with no headache.

So there's a rule of thumb: if you have very new hardware, stick with the latest Ubuntu release (currently 15.10 Wily Werewolf). It ships with a new kernel version and has a bigger driver collection. In the rest of the cases, get the latest LTS (Long Term Support) release (currently 14.04 Trusty Tahr), which has extended support and more stability.

A **great** way of knowing if Ubuntu (and virtually any Linux system) will work well with your machine is using a Live media (the same you'll use to install the OS). Boot from it and test everything, like internet connection (wired/wireless), sound, performance, support to your devices, etc. Once you're sure that it's running fine you can proceed to the installation.